# Paypal java API app between users

Tags: java, api, paypal

I have a question regarding the Paypal Java API. I read their documentation and watched some tutorials about their developer tool to integrate Paypal in my app, but I didn't see nothing about letting users pay each other through Paypal.

To be more explicit, for 2 users, user provides a service through the app for user 2 and user 2 now has to pay user 1 through Paypal within the app. Is it possible, and if it is, how ?

From what I read, the only way I can think about doing this, Paypal API can send an invoice to user 2, but from me (from the application as the receiver) and so the money would go to the app account (express account or whatever it was called) and from there I could forward the money to the user 1. This way would be really inefficient and I wonder if I could make the transaction directly: user 1 sends an invoice to user 2 and user 2 pays that invoice directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Adaptive payment API to let user 1 pay user 2 directly, the app act as the API caller, please see [document here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/)

Comment: this is what I was looking for. thank you very much.